# vscode + python snippet completions: what is `{} ipdb`

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a snippet for inserting an ipdb breakpoint in python code in vscode.

But when doing tab- or ctrl-space completions, `{} ipdb` appears as the first option, causing me always to insert the wrong completion. Selecting that one just inserts a literal `ipdb`. See screenshot.

What is the `{} ipdb` item?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, this only happens after I have inserted one breakpoint, that looks like this:
`import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` (Defined in the vscode python extension)

So the 'ipdb' symbol is imported, and thus pollutes the namespace.

Using a snippet to insert a breakpoint like `from ipdb import set_trace; set_trace()` instead does not import ipdb, so nothing to autocomplete, and no pollution of the autocomplete list.